# How to prove the Abel's Theorem for linear ODE equations system? (see the picture)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, differential-topology

[Just like the picture, how to prove problem d? The theorem is dW/dt = (p11(t) + p22(t) +···+ pnn(t))W](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGac4.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is because
$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$
$$
\det(A+\eps B)=\det(A)\det(I+\eps A^{-1}B)=\det(A)(1+\eps \tr(A^{-1}B)+O(\eps^2))
$$
The derivative of the determinant follows, then insert the ODE.

Comment: could you write out a complete proof?